# IIS Authentication - calling the same server

Tags: c#, .net, security, authentication, iis

I have a problem connecting from **SITE A** to **SITE B** on the same IIS Server.

**SITE A** acts as SPA (aspx) and consumes an API (web api) of **SITE B**, both on .net 4.6.1.

In my deployment env, they are both **subdomains** of the same domain living on the same V-Server.

If I'm on my dev environment it works with the following code:

```
protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string urlParam = "")
    {
        string url = _url;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(urlParam))
        {
            url = $"{_url}?{urlParam}";
        }

        NetworkCredential credentials = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ServiceUser))
        {
            credentials = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ServiceuserDomain)
                ? new NetworkCredential(ServiceUser, Servicepassword, ServiceuserDomain)
                : new NetworkCredential(ServiceUser, Servicepassword);

        }

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler {Credentials = credentials})
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
                try
                {
                    responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                }
                ...
```

I can also connect with that code to my deployed API (**SITE B**)

The web.config of **SITE A** has no "special" configurations. Anonymous Authentication is enabled and Windows Auth disabled.

The web.config of **SITE B** has the following "special" configuration:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" defaultLanguage="c#" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="swagger">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="api">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Which basically allows anonymous access to the site except for /api and /swagger.

If I test the API call to **SITE B** from POSTMAN using the new BETA Authentication NTLM it works aswell. The credential are definitly not wrong, but whenever I go throug the log files of **SITE B** I see:

`2019-06-03 12:08:43 212.147.60.15 GET /api/form/ from=0&to=99/ 443 - IP HTTP/1.1 - - sub.domain.ch 401 0 0 2661 114 0`

`2019-06-03 12:08:43 212.147.60.15 GET /api/form/ from=0&to=99/ 443 - IP HTTP/1.1 - - sub.domain.ch 401 1 3221225581 6661 773 0`

Also, both sub-domain on that server have the same IP address, but I don't think that's related.
Unfortunately in my case I cannot access the Windows Server. I just have a **PLESK** access to manage the domains / files.